# Cannot find HTTP resource on OData REST API

Tags: c#, rest, odata

Hi I have an OData API that I'm trying to run locally but whenever it is being run I cannot load any of the resources.  When I run the API, I get this screen with the information on the entities.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWhLB.png)

Whenever I try to navigate to one using a URL such as http://localhost:51578/Managers, I get an error saying No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51578/Managers'.  Here is the code I have for the Manager Controller.

```js
    public class ManagerController : ODataController
    {
        DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
        private bool ManagerExists(Guid key)
        {
            return db.Managers.Any(p => p.Id == key);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<Manager> Get([FromODataUri] Guid key)
        {
            IQueryable<Manager> result = db.Managers.Where(p => p.Id == key);
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Manager manager)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            db.Managers.Add(manager);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Created(manager);
        }

        [HttpPatch]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] Guid key, Delta<Manager> manager)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            var entity = await db.Managers.FindAsync(key);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            manager.Patch(entity);
            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ManagerExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return Updated(entity);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] Guid key, Manager update)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            if (key != update.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            db.Entry(update).State = EntityState.Modified;
            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ManagerExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return Updated(update);
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] Guid key)
        {
            var manager = await db.Managers.FindAsync(key);
            if (manager == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            db.Managers.Remove(manager);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your WebApiConfig.cs file has the following:

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel(),
            defaultHandler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(innerHandler: new HttpControllerDispatcher(config),
            handlers: new[] { new ODataNullValueMessageHandler() }));
```

This will allow your route to be http://localhost:51578/Managers since we set "routePrefix" to null. If route prefix had something else like "v4" your url would look like http://localhost:51578/v4/Managers.